# How i can hide error provider after displaying error?

Tags: c#

I have a question, maybe someone help me. Do you know made in this program how to do after the error has been removed icon "error provider" disappear if no more error, but it is appear? (excuse me for grammatical error)

```
bool IsValidated = true; //will be checked on button click
void dateTimePicker1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)

{   DateTimePicker datetimepicker = sender as DateTimePicker;

if (datetimepicker.Value == null)

{   errorProvider1.SetError(datetimepicker, "Required");
    IsValidated = false;
} }
void comboBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)

{
   ComboBox combo = sender as ComboBox;
   if(combo.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(combo, "Required");
    IsValidated = false;
}}

void textBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtbox = sender as TextBox;
    if (txtbox.Text == "" || txtbox.Text.Length > 2)
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(txtbox, "Required");
    IsValidated = false;
}}
```

[image]

Comment: Error providers will disappear only if the validation succeds. It will keep displaying otherwise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.seterror%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Call SetError with null to clear the error.

```
if (datetimepicker.Value == null)
{   
    errorProvider1.SetError(datetimepicker, "Required");
    IsValidated = false;
}
else
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(datetimepicker, null);
}
```