# How to clear error from errorprovider one by one

Tags: c#

This is my code for form validation by using errorprovider

```
errorProvider1.Clear();
if (textBox2.Text == "" ||
    textBox3.Text == "" ||
    textBox4.Text == "" ||
    comboBox1.Text == "" ||
    comboBox2.Text == "")
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox2, "Empty Data can't accepted!");
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox3, "Empty Data can't accepted!");
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox4, "Empty Data can't accepted!");
    errorProvider1.SetError(comboBox1, "Empty Data can't accepted!");
    errorProvider1.SetError(comboBox2, "Empty Data can't accepted!");
    return;
}
```

Now there are two problems:
1): when the text comes to text box the error doesn't go
2): i want to remove the error from each text box when it comes into focus

i tried this code but doesn't work..

```
if (textBox2.Focused == true ||
    textBox3.Focused == true ||
    textBox4.Focused == true ||
    comboBox1.Focused == true ||
    comboBox2.Focused == true)
{
    errorProvider1.Clear();
    return;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.seterror?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: `errorProvider1.SetError(textBox2, null);` etc.

Comment: it working bro! but can you tell me a function in which there are many events

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How i can hide error provider after displaying error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372432/how-i-can-hide-error-provider-after-displaying-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.clear?view=netframework-4.7.2

> Calling this method clears all property settings for this ErrorProvider, restoring the properties to their default values. To clear the error message, call the SetError method and pass in Empty for the String value. This removes the error glyph from the specified Control.

Comment: thanks but in this way my validation will be so difficult can you please show me a shortcut to validate my winform

Comment: 2 things you can do:

1- use different errorProviders for the different inputs so that it is easy to control.
2- use a span in the form that should be left visible (this is good for UX) so that the user can see the error message while changing the input.

i'll strongly recommend going with 2, because clearing an error message as soon as the input is changed isn't a very good idea.

Comment: thanks alot but i m new so can you please give me a link on this topic

Comment: what i was suggesting was, under each control that needs to be validated, add a label just beneath them with empty text.

e.g `labelMessageTextBox2`, `labelMessageCombobox2` and set their default values to `false`

then after validating the different control you can change the text values of the label to the errorMessage by using `labelMessage.TextBox2.Text = "Empty Data can't accepted!"`

i hope you are able to continue with you work.